# Python re.sub - replacing character when context does not match

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I am trying to clean up some corrupted csv-Files. One problem is that they contain line feeds within data fields thus splitting one data set in two. I am looking for a piece of python-code that eliminates line feeds should they not be followed by 8 digits. My code so far:

```
filetoparse = open('test.csv', encoding='utf-8')
data = filetoparse.read()

data = re.sub(r'\n(\d{8})',r'§§§\1',data)
data = re.sub(r'\n',r'',data)
data = re.sub(r'§§§','\n',data)
```

Basically I am using the §§§ as a placeholder for correct line feeds, eliminate all line feeds in the data and then replace the placeholders with line feeds again.

It does work, but is there a way to do this more elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead pattern](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

```
data = re.sub(r'\n(?!\d{8})', '', data)
```

For example,

```
import re
data = '''
12345678 foo
bar
baz
12345678 foo
'''
data = re.sub(r'\n(?!\d{8})', '', data)

print(data)
```

yields

```
12345678 foobarbaz
12345678 foo
```